# Can't load json section into a dictionary

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-core

I have a config in appsettings.json like:

```
"ClientId": {
      "US": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "UK": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "PK": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "DK": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "IN": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "LV": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "EE": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      }
    }
```

Now I want to map this section into a dictionary like:

```
 public class ClientIds
    {
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> US { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> UK { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> PK { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> DK { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> IN { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> LV { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> EE { get; set; }
    }
```

But I am getting null every time. Here is my startup config:

```
  services.Configure<ClientIds>((settings) =>
  {
     Configuration.GetSection("ClientId").Bind(settings);
  });
```

and here is my service injection:

```
    private readonly ClientIds _clientIds;
    public MyService(IOptions<ClientIds> clientIds)
    {
      _clientIds = clientIds.Value;
    }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Your sample code works for me. Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

So first of all your json should look like this:

```js
{
"ClientId": {
      "US": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "UK": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "PK": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "DK": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "IN": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "LV": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      },
      "EE": {
        "xxxxxxxx": [ "xxxxxxxx" ]
      }
    }
}
```

Then you'r c# classes should look like this:

```c#
public class US
{
    public List<string> xxxxxxxx { get; set; }
}

public class UK
{
    public List<string> xxxxxxxx { get; set; }
}

public class PK
{
    public List<string> xxxxxxxx { get; set; }
}

public class DK
{
    public List<string> xxxxxxxx { get; set; }
}

public class IN
{
    public List<string> xxxxxxxx { get; set; }
}

public class LV
{
    public List<string> xxxxxxxx { get; set; }
}

public class EE
{
    public List<string> xxxxxxxx { get; set; }
}

public class ClientId
{
    public US US { get; set; }
    public UK UK { get; set; }
    public PK PK { get; set; }
    public DK DK { get; set; }
    public IN IN { get; set; }
    public LV LV { get; set; }
    public EE EE { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ClientId ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

When you have all that look into Newtonsoft JSON nuget package for .NET and use Deserialize method.

It should look like this.

```c#
var object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DestinationObject>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add code In your `startup.cs`

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
 {
     Configuration = configuration;
 }

 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Add this part in ConfigureServices Method

```
  services.Configure<ClientIds>(Configuration.GetSection("ClientId"));
```

Your `ClientIds` class

```
    public class ClientIds
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> US { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> UK { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> PK { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> DK { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> IN { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> LV { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> EE { get; set; }
    }
```